# How to play a mono sound with Java in a 4.0 speakers configuration

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I need to play a .wav mono file in Java (possibly preloading it in RAM) to all the speakers of a 4.0 speakers configuration. I also need to adjust the volume of each of the channels independently while the audio is playing, leaving the system volume unchanged.

This is my current code. It's nowhere near what I need.
How can I do that? Thanks.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

public class AudioPlayer extends Thread {

    private final int BUFFER_SIZE = 128000;
    private File soundFile;
    private AudioInputStream audioStream;
    private AudioFormat audioFormat;
    private SourceDataLine sourceLine;
    String filename;
    Mixer mixer;

    public void load(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public AudioPlayer() {
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            soundFile = new File(filename);
            audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            audioFormat = audioStream.getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
            sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            sourceLine.open(audioFormat);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        sourceLine.start();
        int nBytesRead = 0;
        byte[] abData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while (nBytesRead != -1) {
            try {
                nBytesRead = audioStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                int nBytesWritten = sourceLine.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
            }
        }
        sourceLine.drain();
        sourceLine.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Once the sourceLine is open you can call `sourceLine.getControls()` to see what controls are defined on the line.

Comment: Java Sound supports only stereo.  Typically 4 speaker systems are handled by doubling up stereo, and it is done by the OS.